# How to generate a signed-url which dont expire with aws sdk V2 for S3 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

I want to generate Pre-signed URL for S3 URL which dont expire for Long term using aws SDK V2 in Ruby. While going through the AWS documentation I saw that the signed url gets expired withing one weeks of time. Is there any other way to acheive this SDK V2?

Comment: Why use signed urls at all if you do not want them to expire?

Comment: I can't sign URLs with expirations longer than a week, which is needed for application where we sign the URL's which will be saved in the database and sync through the webservices for other means say : Mobile application.

Comment: will generate Signed URL's for any closed access Articles. For Free access articles I will not generate. This is my use case. Any suggestion on using SDK v2 to sign url's for Longer term expiry?